# Changing images in ImageView with every click

Tags: android

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me with my problem. 
I am trying to change the image in an ImageView when someone clicks on it. I've put my images in an array and I am using a while loop to cycle once through all of them.

My problem is that while the first image (image8, not in the array) shows in the view all the other (after creating the OnClickListener) do not. Actually nothing happens and I am not sure where the mistake is. Thanks in advance.

This is the problematic code:

```
final int array[]=new int[5];
    array[0]= R.drawable.image6;
    array[1]= R.drawable.image4;
    array[2]= R.drawable.image9;
    array[3]= R.drawable.image4;
    array[4]= R.drawable.image5;

ImageView touchView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View touchView, MotionEvent ev) {
    //get coordinates of touch event
        int x = (int)ev.getRawX();
        int y = (int)ev.getRawY();
```

---Code missing---

```
        ((ImageView)touchView).setImageResource(R.drawable.image8);

        touchView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        //Image change on every click
        public void onClick(View touchView) {

            while(counter<5){
            ((ImageView) touchView).setImageResource(array[counter]);
                        counter++;

    });
```

Comment: "int array[]=new int[5];{".  I think that semi-colon is a little lost.  What's it doing there?  Also, the { immediately following the ; isn't closed properly.  Are you trying to do int array[] = new int[]{R.drawable.image6, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image9, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};  ??

Comment: Thank you all for the help. I managed to do what I wanted with the ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change images in a sequence like that and expect anything to show on the screen. You should use the click to start a separate thread that will do the image animation. See the description of the [android.view.animation package](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html). It sounds like the [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html) class will give you exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want the images in the array to change when the user clicks on the view, not to change automatically after some pre-defined time.

Comment: The `AnimationDrawable` is what you want. You just call the `start()` method on a click.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special view for your case. [ImageSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/ImageSwitcher.html) is what you need. There is an [example from android developers](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ImageSwitcher1.html) on how to use it. It should be trivial to adapt the example to your needs.